# How to get the "Type" of an DOM Element?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd, xml-namespaces

I want to use Java's `org.w3c.dom` to access the `xsi:type` of a DOM element (not jaxb or guava or apache.commons, etc.).

I have an XML where an element has a couple of possible types, the base type being abstract -- like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="AbstractBaseType" abstract="true"/>

<xsd:element name="Derived" type="message:DerivedType1"/>
<xsd:complexType name="DerivedType1">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="message:AbstractBaseType">
...
```

In the concrete XML this looks like this:

```
<ns4:root xmlns:ns="..." ...>
  <element xsi:type="ns3:DerivedType1" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    ...
```

Now, `<element>` can be of any type derived from `AbstractBaseType`, in this case it is of type `DerivedType1`, noted in the `xsi:type` attribute. I assume that the XML or XSD standard defines how this works.

I successfully navigated from `<root>` to `<element>`, like so:

```
Document doc = parseToDocument("<ns4:root...");
Element documentElement = doc.getDocumentElement()
Element child = (Element)findChild(documentElement, "element", true, 5);
// now 'child' is the '<element>'-node
// - but how do I get 'DerivedType1'?
Attr type = child.getAttributeNodeNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "type");
String typeName = type.getValue();
```

Now `typeName` contains `"ns3:DerivedType1"`.

**Is there a way to get to `"DerivedType1"` without `typename.split(":")`** (and similar)?

---

#### helper methods

```
private Document parseToDocument(String data) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
  DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // important!
  DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
  return builder.parse(bis);
}

/** breadth first */
private Node findChild(Node node, final String localName, boolean checkNode, final int limitDepth) {
  if(node==null) return null;
  if(limitDepth < 0) return null;
  if(checkNode && StringUtils.equals(node.getLocalName(), localName)) return node;
  final NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
  if(childNodes == null) return null;
  for(int i=0; i < childNodes.getLength(); ++i) {
    final Node child = childNodes.item(i);
    if(StringUtils.equals(child.getLocalName(), localName)) return child;
  }
  final int limitDepthNew = limitDepth - 1;
  for(int i=0; i < childNodes.getLength(); ++i) {
    final Node result = findChild(childNodes.item(i), localName, false, limitDepthNew);
    if(result != null) return result;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set setNamespaceAware(false) ?

Comment: @MikeAdamenko When I do that my `findChild` doesn't work anymore. `getLocalName()` always returns `null` then.

Comment: Does this really have to be done with DOM? The whole thing would be a piece of cake in schema-aware XSLT or XQuery. DOM wasn't designed for XML, it wasn't designed for namespaces, and it certainly wasn't designed for schema-aware processing.

Comment: @MichaelKay I have a xpath and jxpath solution, of course. Also I could do it with Jaxb and reflection. But this is supposed to be lightweight and. And I am quite far already: I have the node  in my hand and fail to access the local name inside the attribute value? That is sort of unbelievable. I guess I am asking about understanding and principles.

Comment: @MichaelKay Ha! Right. My reason is that I want performance without a bunch of dependencies. I challenge you: What is the fastest way to get the xsd-type of a sub-`<element>` or `<root>` (place below root is well known)? Alas, I have a set of similar XSDs each having a `<root>` and `<element>`, I dont know from which the input comes from..The input is a String, It can me any XML and also non-XML data. The result must be quite trustworthy, so no pureRegExprs or substring search. My assumption is that xpath/jxpath/spring solutions do not perform well. But I admit, its only an assumption.

Comment: Performance is going to be dominated by XML parsing and schema validation, not by the query operation.

Comment: @MichaelKay Probably correct guess. Rule No1 with assumptions about performance: Measure, measure. measure. So: I'll have to measure it.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Performance compare: ~2300 xml-files // file-read: 287ms // parse: 1683ms // dom-only-findChild: 43ms // xpath: 853ms. So, parsing *does* dominate, but only by a factor of 2. The dom-only solution is lightning fast.

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't posted ALL your code so I can't run my own tests and compare alternatives. Did you use an API that cached the compiled XPath or was it recompiled on each execution?